# Cassandra : Can same secondary index be used in multiple keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra, cql, secondary-indexes

I am having 2 keyspaces. Keyspace 1 with say 10 tables and Keyspace 2 with additional tables apart from the ones in keyspace 1.

So, Keyspace1 = column_family_1, column_family2 
Keyspace2 = column_family_1,column_family_2,column_family_5

Suppose if I create an index called I1 in column_family_1 under keyspace1, I am unable to create the same index i1 in column_family_1 of keyspace2. Is it a limitation in cassandra? I am getting an error called index already exists when i try to create the same for keyspace 2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The index name doesn't really matter.  Just pick a different name for it.